# how to update position , in android with the help of velocity tracker

Tags: android, pixel

**What i want** : I want to update my carpet position with the velocity of `X` and `Y` in this image with the help of `velocity tracker` .

[image: Image for displaying my figure]

**Actually what i have done** : i have implemented code to move this image by incrementing its position by adding +1 or -1 pixel according to the movement in the previous position of the carpet , and it is working nicely but not according to my expectation . so i switched to `velocity tracker` .

**Now whats the problem with my implementation** : by getting the velocity how can i increase the velocity of the movement ( means i have to +pixels or -pixels according to movement ) the carpet . ,
[image]